# Stripping a player's input in the output terminal

Tags: python, terminal

Is there a way to strip a players input so it doesn't appear in the terminal?

I'm really new to coding, only been at it a few days and it probably shows, but I'm trying to make a game using exclusively the output terminal in VS code.

I'm using a pretty basic battle interface system.

1. Fight
2. Items

I'm trying to use getpass to stop player inputs showing and to stop "1" or "2" appearing in the terminal when a player inputs a decision.
With this system however I'm getting a very ugly "Password:" showing up in the item menu that I can't seem to move... is there a better way for me to approach this other than getpass?
Is there a way to just remove "Password:" from the output terminal?
Apologies for the ugly code and the dozens of mistakes I have probably made.
Also, apologies if this question has a really simple answer, but I have lost the best part of 2 days scouring the internet for alternatives and I just can't get it to work the way I want.

```
import wave, sys, time, random, os, winsound, getpass
from inputimeout import inputimeout, TimeoutOccurred
from playsound import playsound
input = getpass.getpass
password = None
character_name = "Lister" 
character = character_name

def typewriter(message):
    for char in message:
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        if char =="\n":
            time.sleep(1)
        elif char == "." or char == "?" or char =="!":
            time.sleep(0.5)
        else:
            time.sleep(0.05)

def typewriter2(message):
    for char in message:
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        if char =="\n":
            time.sleep(1)
        elif char == "." or char == "?" or char =="!":
            time.sleep(2)
        else:
            time.sleep(0.05)

def typewriter3(message):
    for char in message:
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        if char =="\n":
            time.sleep(1)
        elif char == "." or char == "?" or char =="!":
            time.sleep(0.5)
        else:
            time.sleep(0.001)

def alien3():

    distanceFromLeft = 150

    while distanceFromLeft >= 80:
        print(" " * (distanceFromLeft - 1) +  r"        __.,,------.._  ")
        print(" " * (distanceFromLeft - 1) +  r"     ,'\"   _      _   \"`.")
        print(" " * (distanceFromLeft - 1) +  r"    /.__, ._  -=- _\"`    Y")
        print(" " * (distanceFromLeft - 1) +  r"   (.____.-.`      \"\"`   j ")
        print(" " * (distanceFromLeft - 1) +  r"    VvvvvvV`.Y,.    _.,-'       ,     ,     ,")
        print(" " * (distanceFromLeft - 1) +  r"        Y    ||,   '\"\         ,/    ,/    ./")
        print(" " * (distanceFromLeft - 1) +  r"        |   ,'  ,     `-..,'_,'/___,'/   ,'/   ,")
        print(" " * (distanceFromLeft - 1) +  r"   ..  ,;,,',-'\"\,\'  ,  .     '     ' \"\"\' \'--,/    .. ..")
        print(" " * (distanceFromLeft - 1) +  r" ,'. `.`---'     `, /  , Y -=-    ,'   ,   ,. .`-..||_|| ..")
        print(" " * (distanceFromLeft - 1) +  r"ff\\`. `._        /f ,'j j , ,' ,   , f ,  \=\ Y   || ||`||_..")
        print(" " * (distanceFromLeft - 1) +  r"l` \` `.`.\"`-..,-\' j  /./ /, , / , / /l \   \=\l   || `\' || ||...")
        print(" " * (distanceFromLeft - 1) +  r" `  `   `-._ `-.,-/ ,' /`\"/-/-/-/-\"''\"`.`.  `'.\--`'--..`'_`' || ,")
        print(" " * (distanceFromLeft - 1) +  r"            \"`-_,',  ,'  f    ,   /      `._    ``._     ,  `-.`'//         ,")
        print(" " * (distanceFromLeft - 1) +  r"          ,-\"'' _.,-'    l_,-'_,,'          \"`-._ . \"`. /|     `.'\ ,       |")
        print(" " * (distanceFromLeft - 1) +  r"        ,',.,-'\"          \=) ,`-.         ,    `-'._`.V |       \ // .. . /j")
        print(" " * (distanceFromLeft - 1) +  r"        |f\\               `._ )-.\"`.     /|         `.| |        `.`-||-\\/")
        print(" " * (distanceFromLeft - 1) +  r"        l` \`                 \"`._   \"`--' j          j' j          `-`---'")
        print(" " * (distanceFromLeft - 1) +  r"         `  `                     \"`_,-','/       ,-'\"  /")
        print(" " * (distanceFromLeft - 1) +  r"                                 ,'\",__,-'       /,, ,-'")
        print(" " * (distanceFromLeft - 1) +  r"                                 Vvv'            VVv'")
        time.sleep(0.05)
        os.system('cls')  
        distanceFromLeft -= 1
        if distanceFromLeft == 80:
            alienstatic()
            break
        else:
            os.system('cls')

def alienstatic():
    print(" " * 80 +  r"        __.,,------.._  ")
    print(" " * 80 +  r"     ,'\"   _      _   \"`.")
    print(" " * 80 +  r"    /.__, ._  -=- _\"`    Y")
    print(" " * 80 +  r"   (.____.-.`      \"\"`   j ")
    print(" " * 80 +  r"    VvvvvvV`.Y,.    _.,-'       ,     ,     ,")
    print(" " * 80 +  r"        Y    ||,   '\"\         ,/    ,/    ./")
    print(" " * 80 +  r"        |   ,'  ,     `-..,'_,'/___,'/   ,'/   ,")
    print(" " * 80 +  r"   ..  ,;,,',-'\"\,\'  ,  .     '     ' \"\"\' \'--,/    .. ..")
    print(" " * 80 +  r" ,'. `.`---'     `, /  , Y -=-    ,'   ,   ,. .`-..||_|| ..")
    print(" " * 80 +  r"ff\\`. `._        /f ,'j j , ,' ,   , f ,  \=\ Y   || ||`||_..")
    print(" " * 80 +  r"l` \` `.`.\"`-..,-\' j  /./ /, , / , / /l \   \=\l   || `\' || ||...")
    print(" " * 80 +  r" `  `   `-._ `-.,-/ ,' /`\"/-/-/-/-\"''\"`.`.  `'.\--`'--..`'_`' || ,")
    print(" " * 80 +  r"            \"`-_,',  ,'  f    ,   /      `._    ``._     ,  `-.`'//         ,")
    print(" " * 80 +  r"          ,-\"'' _.,-'    l_,-'_,,'          \"`-._ . \"`. /|     `.'\ ,       |")
    print(" " * 80 +  r"        ,',.,-'\"          \=) ,`-.         ,    `-'._`.V |       \ // .. . /j")
    print(" " * 80 +  r"        |f\\               `._ )-.\"`.     /|         `.| |        `.`-||-\\/")
    print(" " * 80 +  r"        l` \`                 \"`._   \"`--' j          j' j          `-`---'")
    print(" " * 80 +  r"         `  `                     \"`_,-','/       ,-'\"  /")
    print(" " * 80 +  r"                                 ,'\",__,-'       /,, ,-'")
    print(" " * 80 +  r"                                 Vvv'            VVv'")
    print(playerart)

#hero_attributes Assigns attribures to the Lister Character_Loot has no function at the moment but could be called later
class Player (object):
    name = "????"
    health = 30
    strength = 10
    invent = {"Medkit" : 1, "Grenade" : 1, "Assault Rifle" : 1}

#enemy_attributes_Assigns the enemy attributes to Xeno
class Xeno (object):
    name = "Xeno"
    health = 20
    strength = 8

#enemy_attributes_Assigns the enemy attributes to Software Engineer
class Engineer (object):
    name = "Software Engineer"
    health = 15
    strength = 6

class BossAlien (object):
    name = "Big Mama Jama"
    health = 50
    strength = 10

def loot(enemy):
    if enemy == "Xeno":
        loot = ["Medkit", "Grenade", "Assault Rifle"]
        chanceloot = random.randint (0, 2) 
        lootdrop = loot[chanceloot] #randomly selects a loot item from the list
        if lootdrop == "Medkit":
            Player.invent["Medkit"] += 1
            print("You have found a Medkit!")
        elif lootdrop == "Grenade":
            Player.invent["Grenade"] += 1
            print("You found a Grenade!")
        elif lootdrop == "Assault Rifle":
            Player.invent["Assault Rifle"] += 1
            print("You found a Assault Rifle!")
        return lootdrop
    elif enemy == "Engineer":
        Player.invent["Key Card"] = 1
        print("You found a Key Card.")
    elif enemy == "BossAlien":
        Player.invent["Key Card"] = 1 #Change to what is needed pls
        print("You found a Key Card.")

#Game_Over_This gives an ending to the game and also a high score_referenced in option 1 & 2 below
def gameover(Player):
    if Player.health < 1:
        print("YOU DIED")
        #deathbyxeno() #replace with toms death (function)
        exit() # Remove

### !!!Battle Mechanic!!! ###
def battlestate(Player, enemy):
    
    
    
    alien3()
    typewriter(f"""\n{enemy.name} has appeared and it looks hungry""")
    time.sleep(3)
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

    while enemy.health > 0 : #while loop will repeat the option to run or fight as long as the enemy health is over 0
        def menu():
            print("")
        alienstatic()
        choice = input("\n1. Fight \n2. Use item\n" )

        if choice == "1":

            typewriter(f"You attack the {enemy.name}\n") #displays a message saying what enemy you are attacking
            hitchance = random.randint(1,10) #hitchance is an int from 1-10

            if hitchance > 4: #if hitchance is over 4 the attack is successful_gives a 50% chance of success_can be changed to make the game harder or easier

                enemy.health = enemy.health - Player.strength
                
                typewriter(f"You shoot the {enemy.name}, their health is now {enemy.health}\n")
                if enemy.health < 0:
                    enemy.health = 0

                if enemy.health > 0:        #Enemy attacks player
                    Player.health = Player.health - enemy.strength
                    typewriter(f"The {enemy.name} attacks, you now have {Player.health} health.\n")
                    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
                    gameover(Player)

    #reset enemy health_this will reset the health of the enemy after battle
                else:
                    enemy.health =  18
                                           
                        
                    typewriter(f"You have defeated the {enemy.name}.\n") #prints message when enemy defeated
                    loot(enemy)
                    return
                               
            else:
                typewriter("You miss\n")       #<<<
                typewriter(f"The {enemy.name} takes advantage of your miss and hits you for a critical!\n")
                Player.health = Player.health - enemy.strength
                typewriter(f"You only have {Player.health} health remaining\n")
                time.sleep(3)
                os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

        elif choice == "2": # Using items mechanic
            if Player.invent == {"Medkit" : 0, "Grenade" : 0, "Assault Rifle" : 0}: # Recognises whether invent has any items in it
                print("You have no items!")
                menu()
            else:
                print("Use which item?\n") # If so, pick one
                for count, i in enumerate(Player.invent):
                    print(f"{count+1} =", i, Player.invent[i])
                print("4 = Exit Inventory")
            
                ch_item = input()

                if ch_item == "1" and Player.invent["Medkit"] > 0: # Sep check for the item and how it is used
                    Player.health = 30
                    print("Your health is now ", Player.health)
                    Player.invent["Medkit"] -= 1
                    menu()
                elif ch_item == "1":
                    print("Sorry, you have no Medkits.")
                    menu()
                elif ch_item == "2" and Player.invent["Grenade"] > 0:
                    enemy.health -= 20
                    print("The  ", enemy.name, " is hurt. Its health is now ", enemy.health)
                    Player.invent["Grenade"] -= 1
                    if enemy.health <= 0:
                        print("You have defeated the", enemy.name) #prints message when enemy defeated
                        loot(enemy)
                        return
                    menu()
                elif ch_item == "2":
                    print("Sorry, you have no Grenades.")
                    menu()
                elif ch_item == "3" and Player.invent["Assault Rifle"] > 0:
                    Player.strength += 20
                    print("Your attack is now ", Player.strength)
                    Player.invent["Assault Rifle"] -= 1
                    menu()
                elif ch_item == "3":
                    print("Sorry, you don't have a Assault Rifle.")
                    menu()
                elif ch_item == "4":
                    menu()
                else:
                    menu()
        else:
            menu()

playerart = """                      ______
                   ,-~   _  ^^~-.,
                 ,^        -,____ ^,         
                /           (____)  |      
               ;  .---._    | | || _|     
               | |      ~-.,\ | |!/ |     
               ( |    ~<-.,_^\|_7^ ,|     
               | |      ", 77>   (T/|   
               |  \_      )/<,/^\)i(|
               (    ^~-,  |________||
               ^!,_    / /, ,'^~^',!!_,..---.
                \_ "-./ /   (-~^~-))' =,__,..>-,
                  ^-,__/#w,_  '^' /~-,_/^\      )
               /\  ( <_    ^~~--T^ ~=, \  \_,-=~^\ 
  .-==,    _,=^_,.-"_  ^~*.(_  /_)    \ \,=\      )
 /-~;  \,-~ .-~  _,/ \    ___[8]_      \ T_),--~^^)
   _/   \,,..==~^_,.=,\   _.-~O   ~     \_\_\_,.-=}
 ,{       _,.-<~^\  \ \\      ()  .=~^^~=. \_\_,./
,{ ^T^ _ /  \  \  \  \ \)    [|   \ih8code>
  ^T~ ^ { \  \ _\.-|=-T~\\    () ()\<||>,' )
   +     \ |=~T  !       Y    [|()  \ ,'  / """
def player_animation():
    print(playerart)

battlestate(Player, Xeno)
```

Comment: It's very unlikely all that code is necessary to illustrate the problem you're having. Please [edit] your question and provide a (runnable) [mre].

Comment: Apologies, throughout the code I have it recalling the animation and ascii art quite a bit throughout the code to keep the menu the same throughout the battle... I figured it would just be easier to show everything I have at the moment because any help that works in a smaller space will be useless to me if it doesn't work in the larger space.

Comment: It wasn't that I didn't put in the effort, I genuinely thought it would be best for you to see everything I see so that you can reproduce the same error that I can in the same space that I can, I don't know what is causing the problem so I wouldn't know which bits of code to remove, but I guess you are right- I'm just new to all this, I apologise.

Comment: I understand, which is precisely why I made my original comment/suggestion. Often less is better here (and folks will ask if they need to see more of it). I also suggest you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

`getpass` accepts a parameter `prompt` and thus you can just pass empty string in order to omit `Password:`  prefix ?

```
>>> from getpass import getpass
>>> inp = getpass("")

>>> print(inp)
I typed this
>>>
```

Comment: I've tried using getpass.getpass(prompt=""),
Only problem with this is it results in a "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"
and I can't seem to get around it

Comment: @Tom: Hint - in the context of your code, `getpass` _is_ a module unlike it is in this answer (hence the `TypeError` you're getting)

Comment: I think I figured it out. But now I'm getting a 'str' object is not callable. So in fixing that first problem now my while statement is just looping rapidly instead of waiting for an input. :(